# How to create OPC UA Certificates manually?

Tags: .net, opc, opc-ua

I'm trying to program an OPC UA Client that runs as a module of a higher level software and should be configurable by this software.
That's why I want to make the configuration using different commands and not by loading a configuration file.
I use the SDK of the OPC Foundation. but the Sample Applications only use the
"LoadApplicationConfiguration" and "CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate" to create configuration and certificate.

Currently my certificate is created with :
CertificateFactory.CreateCertificate()

```
            // find the certificate in the store. create a new certificate if not found.
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate =
                _configuration.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.Find(true) ??
                Opc.Ua.CertificateFactory.CreateCertificate(
                    _configuration.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.StoreType,
                    _configuration.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.StorePath,
                    _configuration.ApplicationUri,
                    _configuration.ApplicationName,
                    null,
                    null,
                    2048,
                    120);
```

I thought the manually created certificate works fine, but now I tried to implement Sign/ SignAndEncrypt and can't create a connection anymore. When I use the certificate created by another ClientApplication it works fine.

So my question is: Does my certificate need a special format or special parameters to allow Sign/ SignAndEncrypt?
Has anyone an example to solve this issue, or is this the wrong way?

The background is, that I want to be able to configure store type and path later. At the moment the certificates are stored in the Windows store.

Comment: You can look at the attributes of each of the certificates and see which are missing in yours.
Maybe yours does not have an Issuer. Although all depends on how restrictive the server is accepting certificates, there's not a fixed rule about that

Comment: okay. the issuer is a combination of application name and computername. That seems to fit. But I will check the other parameters now and give an update when I'm ready..

Comment: The thing that's a combination is the Application URI, for example : urn:localhost:appname. The issuer name is usually a single name

Comment: I don't mean the URI. My issuer name looks like:
"CN=MyUaClient, DC=Sobo-PC".

But finally it works and the certificate was okay. The problem was that the server didn't trust my certificate when I try to use sign&encrypt.

But when I used the certificate without security mode the connection was established. It seems that the server uses just the Subject or Issuer Name for user identification but doesn't really check the certificate in this mode. That's why I thought my certificate works fine. Was a little confusing.

Thanks for your advice tonteria24!

Comment: You welcome ... but you don't need a certificate with security == none. The real test is to establish a connection with Sign or with Sign & Encrypt, if not you don't know if your certificate is ok.. The certificate is not only the identity of the client also contains the keys used for signing and encryption.  CN means Common Name, it's not the issuer, it's not the ApplicationURI.